# How to reshape tables with dplyr in R using years from column

Tags: r, dplyr

i'm working with R trying to change the shape of one table. For example, in this case, i have the next data:

```
pet <- c("dog", "cat", "fish", "dog", "cat", "fish", "dog", "cat", "fish")
year <- c("2018", "2018","2018","2019", "2019","2019","2020", "2020","2020")
total <- c("3", "4","10", "5", "2", "3","6","7","8")


animal_store <- data.frame(pet,year,total)
```

In other view:

```
   pet year total
1  dog 2018     3
2  cat 2018     4
3 fish 2018    10
4  dog 2019     5
5  cat 2019     2
6 fish 2019     3
7  dog 2020     6
8  cat 2020     7
9 fish 2020     8
```

I wonder to know how can i get the next table, i tried before with `dplyr()`, especifically with `summarise()` but r said there is a problem with my code:

```
Pet   2018  2019  2020
dog      3     4    10
cat      4     2     7
fish    10     3     8
```

Any help or another point of view will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If we convert the `factor` column of 'total' to `numeric`, `xtabs` from `base R` can be used

```
animal_store$total <- as.numeric(as.character(animal_store$total))
xtabs(total ~ pet + year, animal_store)
```

Or with `tapply`

```
with(animal_store, tapply(total, list(pet, year), FUN = I))
#     2018 2019 2020
#cat     4    2    7
#dog     3    5    6
#fish   10    3    8
```

---

In `tidyverse`, we can use `pivot_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
animal_store %>% 
     pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = total)
```